# How to load json files list into dropdown box using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, angularjs-1.5

I have three `json` files, I wanted to load or get those `json` files list into my dropdown box. How can I do this using `angularjs` ? Please help me and thanks in advance. I have created [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KJYgDIxr1y4YH8udaq3k?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

I have got to know and I am getting my json values list in the dropdown box by putting like:

```
 <select name="jsonfilenames">
     <option name="none">Select</option>
     <option name="test1 json" >{{values1}}</option>
     <option name="test2 json">{{values2}}</option>
     <option name="test3 json">{{values3}}</option>
 </select>
```